# How can you figure out the dependencies of your project?

Tags: programming, libraries

I am going to start a project soon, and want to make sure all libs are included that are not natively installed. Is there a way to check this without compiling on a clean machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building a .deb package, you can use `pbuilder` to do a test build. Since `pbuilder` builds in a clean `chroot` environment, it's a bit like building on a clean machine, without the hassle. And if you're missing any build dependencies, you'll quickly find out.